# python multiprocessing Pool(1)

Tags: python, threadpool, python-multiprocessing, pool

is multiprocessing.Pool(1) the same as a normal for loop?

I'm asking this because I would like to leave the choice to use or not the parallel computing but I don't know if Pool(1) with map is actually less performing than a normal for loop
Thanks

Comment: No, it will use a separate process and will have the overhead of a separate process.

Comment: "is multiprocessing.Pool(1) the same as a normal for loop?" No. No it is not. That creates a multiprocessing pool with 1 process. And yes, it would be less performant than a regular for-loop. probably by a lot. Have you *checked*?

Comment: What you should be comparing is  method `map` in class `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` with built-in function `map` and not a for loop. But, the former will still be less performant.